# remote connection not working despite pg_hba.conf entry

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

I want to connect to `postgres-12` from a `postgres-14` server in order to get dumps from the remote.

Apparently there is a connection problem when trying to access the remote postgres server though.

```bash
postgres@dvzsn-rd5482:> hostname -I
10.4.91.68
postgres@dvzsn-rd5482:> psql -p 5449 -h 10.4.91.32
psql: error: connection to server at "10.4.91.32", port 5449 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.4.91.68", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

so it complains about a missing `pg_hba.conf` entry on the remote for `10.4.91.68`

however ...

```
postgres@dvzsn-rd1941:> psql -p 5449 -c "SELECT * FROM pg_hba_file_rules WHERE address = '10.4.91.68';"
 line_number |   type    |  database  | user_name  |  address   |     netmask     | auth_method | options | error
-------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+---------+-------
          92 | host      | {all}      | {all}      | 10.4.91.68 | 255.255.255.255 | md5         |         |
          93 | hostnossl | {postgres} | {postgres} | 10.4.91.68 | 255.255.255.255 | md5         |         |
(2 rows)
```

in my eyses the first line should be sufficient even.

Any idea on what I am not seeing? It does not seem to be `listen_addresses`

```
 postgres@dvzsn-rd1941:> psql -c "SHOW listen_addresses"
 listen_addresses
------------------
 *
`
```

Comment: did you reload the database configuration? pg_hba_file_rules works with a file, while authorization uses a saved configuration in the server memory.

Comment: In addition, make sure that 10.4.91.32 is the same as the local machine. What does the PostgreSQL server log say?

Comment: Perhaps your connection attempt matches one of the earlier 90 lines in the pg_hba file?

Comment: logs on the remote say the same thing: `no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.4.91.68", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off`

Comment: i did do a `pg_ctl -p 5449 reload` on the remote

Comment: none of the earlier lines in `pg_hba.conf` match my request

Answer (score -1):

Please try to change subnet mask to 255.255.255.0 as you specified 24 bytes network IP address

Comment: `/24` instead of `/32` does not change anything to the better either. Apart from that I have good experience with using `/32` subnet (narrrowing things down to that one exact address) for those entries

Comment: Can You please attach here whole pg_hba file?

Comment: it was resolved after all. Don't really know how and why. It is working all of a sudden with `host  all    all    10.4.91.68/32   md5`